# Attach video to email in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to attach a video to an email. It is not a local video so I write it to a file. Then I get the data from that file and attach to the email. When the email comes up, the only thing there is the file name "video.mp4" with no video.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/video.mp4"];
NSLog(@"writing");
BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
if (success){

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempPath];
    NSLog(@"path: %@", tempPath);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        [controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"video.mp4"];
        NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's unsuccessful? In my experience, that's all `MFMailComposeViewController` shows for video attachments. Have you looked at the email you received to see if an MP4 is attached?

Comment: @Linuxios You are right, it does send. Do you know if there is a way to show the video in the email? I'm not sure if users will understand that the video is attached if all it says is "video.mp4" in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I think only approach to try is formatting mail as HTML. Otherwise you will always sending an attachment.

```
NSString *messageBody = @" /*Some HTML format containing HTML5 video player*/";
[controller setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
```

So you need to look for suitable CSS and HTML tags for your video. But don't forget to test it with most e-mail clients as you may see different looks.